# Zend Check if a Module is installed and active

Tags: zend-framework

i want to create a module for my running application. I chose module, so that it can be added optionally to the application.

I want to create the following. When the module is installed (module subfolder is placed in /application/modules/) i want to add a new button/function to my application.

I want to check for this installed module in a controller action.

Is there a way to do this?

Regards,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
$modules = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getControllerDirectory();
```

The modules are then given by the keys of the array that is returned:

```
array(
    'default' => '../application/controllers',
    'blog'    => '../modules/blog/controllers',
    'news'    => '../modules/news/controllers',
)
```

You can then perform the check in your action:

```
if (array_key_exists('myModule', $modules)) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I will try it directly. Maybe you can answer another question meanwhile:

Is it possible to modify the navigation structure, when a new module is installed?

Comment: The above check can be put wherever you want. So yes, you could use this check in the code that generates your navigation menu.

Comment: I generate my navigation via Zend_Navigation. The navigationstructure is configured via a XML file. Is there a simple way to modify this structure?

Comment: After you've loaded the `Zend_Navigation` object from your XML file, you can still edit it using its methods. Have a look at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.navigation.containers.html#zend.navigation.containers.iterating or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7954269/zend-navigation-change-navigation-label

Answer (score 0):

In order to let the application generate the new menu, what I like to do is to create a global var that holds the menu.  This way, in the new module Bootstrap, I can add items to the menu.  The code that I use is rather long so I will not post it here but you can email me if you want it.